# Netbeans Custom Component with Custom-Class Property

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, properties, custom-component

I have a question about implementing a Swing control which uses a custom class as one of its properties. My goal is to use this control within the netbeans IDE and configure it in design-time like any other component. I already implemented a custom property editor for my *ConnectionInfo* object which works fine.

However - when I configure my *IntLEDs ConnectionInfo* property in Netbeans and save it, I can see, in the generated code by Netbeans, that it had troubles to init my *ConnectionInfo* class.

This is actually what the Netbeans IDE generated:

```
intLED1.setConnection(???);
```

So I guess that Netbeans doesn't know how to instantiate my *ConnectionInfo* class. 
But how to tell Netbeans how to do it? :)

This code is basicly a stripped version of my component

```
public class IntLED extends JPanel {

  private ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo("", 11159, "", "", Variable.VARIABLE_TYPE.INT);

  public IntLED() {
      initComponents();

      PropertyEditorManager.registerEditor(ConnectionInfo.class, PviCpuPropertyEditor.class);
  }

  public ConnectionInfo getConnection() {
      return connection;
  }

  public void setConnection(ConnectionInfo connection) {
      this.connection = connection;
  }
}
```

Here the *ConnectionInfo* code. Just some members and Getters/Setters.

```
public class ConnectionInfo {
  private String pviHost = "";
  private int    pviPort = 11159;
  private String pviTask = "";
  private String pviVarname = "";
  private Variable.VARIABLE_TYPE pviType;

  public ConnectionInfo() {
  }

  public ConnectionInfo(String pviHost, int pviPort, String pviTask, String pviVarname, Variable.VARIABLE_TYPE type) {
      this.pviHost = pviHost;
      this.pviPort = pviPort;
      this.pviTask = pviTask;
      this.pviVarname = pviVarname;
      this.pviType = type;
  }



  public String getPviHost() {
      return pviHost;
  }

  public void setPviHost(String pviHost) {
      this.pviHost = pviHost;
  }

  public int getPviPort() {
      return pviPort;
  }

  public void setPviPort(int pviPort) {
      this.pviPort = pviPort;
  }

  public String getPviTask() {
      return pviTask;
  }

  public void setPviTask(String pviTask) {
      this.pviTask = pviTask;
  }

  public String getPviVarname() {
      return pviVarname;
  }

  public void setPviVarname(String pviVarname) {
      this.pviVarname = pviVarname;
  }

  public Variable.VARIABLE_TYPE getPviType() {
      return pviType;
  }

  public void setPviVarname(Variable.VARIABLE_TYPE pviType) {
      this.pviType = pviType;
  }
}
```

I also tried to put the members of the *ConnectionInfo*-Class directly into my *IntLED*-Class which works fine! But I really need to let the user configure those Members directly in one editor since the editor also provides a tester to test those settings et cetera.

I hope someone can point me to the right direction :)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the 'missing link' between my Custom Property and the Matisse Code generator!

In my Custom Property Editor (which extends `PropertyEditorSupport`) I did **not** override the method `getJavaInitializationString()`.
Apperently when this method is not overwritten, it returns '???' which is exactly what I saw.

Here is how I fixed it:

```
@Override
public String getJavaInitializationString() {
    return String.format("new ConnectionInfo(\"%s\", %d, \"%s\", \"%s\", Variable.VariableType.BOOLEAN)", getValue().getHost(), getValue().getPort(), getValue().getTask(), getValue().getVarname()); 
}
```

Surely there should be some Nullpointer checks and so on. But this is basicly how to tell Matisse how to init your Custom Class!

Comment: That's handy to know.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question, but as I see it you want to be able to add your custom `JPanel` (`IntLED`) as a component that you can use in the GUI Editor (Matisse) like every other component?

There is an answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409887/963076) that explains how to add custom components to the GUI Editor.

EDIT:

Ok, I see. To change the code that Netbeans is generating, you should look for that parameter in the `Properties` dialog for that component. Right click the component and click "Properties." Then find `connection` in the list of properties. `connection` should appear because Netbeans looks for all `get()` and `set()` methods and adds them as properties that you can edit. Once you find `connection` press the `...` button to the right. It'll bring up a dialog allowing you to set that component's property. You'll probably need to select "custom code".

(In the pictures below, I used the `columnModel` property as an illustration).

[image]

From the screen below, select "custom code".

[image]

Comment: Hi ryvantage. Thank you alot for your response. Unfortunately my problem is not the custom component (`IntLED`) itself, but the `ConnectionInfo`-Member of my `IntLED`. Whenever I configure the `ConnectionInfo`-Member using Matisse and then save the form, Netbeans generates invalid Java code within the initComponents() method. `intLED1.setConnection(???);`. And this is the Problem I encouter. The three Questionmarks should be something like `intLED1.setConnection(new ConnectionInfo("host", 12345, "task", "type", Types.Boolean);` depending on how I configured the Member in Matisse. Happy xmas :)

Comment: Dear ryvantage. At first let me thank you again for taking your time to answer me. I am aware of the fact that I can use custom code to init my controls. However my want to know how to 'teach' netbeans how to construct my `Connection` class with the settings I configured in the Property editor. I sadly cannot post images bacause lack of rep. Instead I uploaded what I have done so far at http://imgur.com/XuXXSce . I hope this helps to understand my actual issue. I am sorry if my question was not clear enough.

Comment: I found the problem :) See my answer below. I cannot accept it yet. But this is exactly how to solve it! Thank you very much for your time ryvantage!