# Netbeans GUI builder - custom class properties category

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, matisse

I want to know how to categorize the properties of my custom JComponent in the netbeans GUI properties editor.

[image: example of properties editor]

so anyways. There is a property "key" in there and it is under the category "other properties". How would I make a new property category for it so it is under a category for example "Special properties"?

The code in question is like this:

```
public void setKey(String ke) {
    //functionality
}

public String getKey() {
    return k.getText();
}
```

I know this is possible. I saw such a feature somewhere a long time ago but I cannot find it back.

Comment: Hopefully this will steer you in the right direction. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760389/netbeans-custom-component-with-custom-class-property][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760389/netbeans-custom-component-with-custom-class-property

Comment: @Jazzman the links you give are for custom editors in the properties :/ thanks though.