# Edit code in NetBeans Swings class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

While creating a new project in Netbeans, I selected Java with Swings class. Then I created a form using drag and drop in Design. However, when I navigated to its Source, much of it was uneditable. Things like hiding a field unless a button is clicked etc. couldn't be done.

Is there a way to make the code in source of a java swings class editable?

Comment: You can’t modify the “unedited” sections, they get regenerated anyway, but you can reference the components on other parts of you code and modify there states. Having said that , personally I’d avoid the form designer - but that’s me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change non-editable/generated code in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131589/how-to-change-non-editable-generated-code-in-netbeans)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the answer!