# text stuck in non-editable line in netbeansIDE

Tags: java, netbeans-8, gui-builder

just have a very big problem with my project, i work on a java project on **NetBeansIDE 8.2** i'm on Windows8 x86, in netbeans GUI Builder when i changed a component variable_name to another one, the old variable_name have been stuck in the **non-editable** line of code, i tried search in netbeans community and searchs in web but got nothing, it occurs after i updated my JDK from(JDK 8u191) to (JDK 8u202), tried same operation on some other project and it makes them useless too (stuck code).

> **my question:**
>   is there is a way to fix this? or edit this **non-editable** lines?

it's like this [image: cannot edit these lines contains error]

`password_showing` is old one and cannot be deleted,

there is:

- copy code inside event
- delete event
- recreate event
- paste code inside

but it's a big project i cannot do this for every single event, is there is a way to solve this? thanks!

Comment: The non-editable code is non-editable for a reason. You can change all the code that is generated through the GUI editor - including renaming of variables of GUI components

Comment: how did you rename it?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of your question, but some of the comments and answers to [How to change non-editable/generated code in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17131589/2985643) might be helpful.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i changed some setting for generated code in GUI Builder but nothing changed, it still guarded code

Comment: @Null from right_click menu -> "Change Variable Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you changed the name through `Property/name`, it changes the name but not the name of event methods and auto generated codes.
The correct way to rename a control in *netbeans* is to right click on it and say rename: `right click on the control -> change variable name`

*Update* regarding your current issue:

You may fix your current issue withig `*.form`, `*.java` and `*.xml` related files in the project but it's not recommended and you may stuck more and face more issues!

Comment: actually i changed variable name by RightClick on component then "Change Variable Name", yes i fixed this like you said, corrected line inside *.java file with normal text editor and saved it, then re-open project, **maybe** it's not the best way but it works fine! thank you =)