# How to unlock private command to public in netbeans JFrame form?

Tags: netbeans

As the title , I have problem with create a GUI in JFrame form.
The problem is when I double actionperformed in a button in design view then the source code will show

```
private void BtnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
}
```

but the command is lock , since I need change the private to public, is it possible I edit it??
thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You have several options...

1) You can make a public method that calls your private method:

```
private void jButton17ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // Your action
}                                         
public void jButtonAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jButton17ActionPerformed(evt);
}
```

2) You could make the button itself public and call the `doClick()` method.
To do this, right click on the button and press "Customize Code"

[image: Customize Code]

Then change the button's access at the bottom from `private` to `public`.

[image]

3) You could pass your `JButton` as a parameter to whatever method/class needs to call it (because, even if you make the button public, you still need to access an instance of the containing class to reference it).

4) You could do what everyone else who read this question but didn't answer is thinking: hand-write your code [(but I won't judge you for using Netbeans ;) )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581918/963076).

On a side note, usually there are better ways to solve problems than accessing components and their action methods from outside of the class. I can say I've only needed to do something like this once or twice in my career, and even then I ended up finding a more elegant solution those problems. So, if I were you I would look for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is:
you can edit this source that you want change , with notepad++ or other and change it to public. then change `sourceName.form` , the this node to public and save it.

or other way is :

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //your code
            }

        });
```