# How to set a background image for the tabbed pane in java swing using Netbeans GUI Builder?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

I am trying to set a background image for tabbed pane in java swing application but i can keep only colors how to go through with image ?

EDIT from comment

i want the image for the full tabbed pane. if i set image to label and keep it for full screen i cant keep any components on the label

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Look [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

Comment: Before using GUI Builder, I recommend you to read [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468328/java-gui-builder-or-hand-coding)

Comment: i want the image for the full tabbed pane. if i set image to label and keep it for full screen i cant keep any components on the label

Comment: read the link carefully

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do using GUI Builder. Instead of using the drag and drop in the `JFrame` form to drag and drop `JPanel`s for the `JTabbedPane`, do this.

1. Create a `JPanel` form class
2. Layout the `JPanel` with all the components you want.
3. In the constructor add this to load the image. Use your own image path

   ```
   public class TabPanelOne extends javax.swing.JPanel {
       Image img;
       public TabPanelOne() {
           try {
               img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow5.png"));
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(TabPanelOne.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
           initComponents();
       }
   ```
4. Override the `paintComponent` method of the `JPanel` and draw the image

   ```
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
   }
   ```
5. You should have an empty `JTabbedPane` in your `JFrame` form class. In the constructor, just add the `JPanel` form

   ```
   public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
       public NewJFrame() {
           initComponents();
           jTabbedPane1.add("panel1", new TabPanelOne());
       }
   ```

[image]

Comment: The question is how to make transparent tabbed pane not a component or a panel inside it.

Comment: @peeskillet how to add a image inside the panel i used this code its running but image is not shown
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("logo.png");
jLabel5.setIcon(icon);

Comment: @Suresh **Don't** add a `JLabel`. You won't be able to add components on top of it. You need to paint the image onto the `JPanel` form. You need to follow the instructions above. Create  separate `JPanel` form, **don't** drag an drop a `JPanel` on to the `JFrame` form. Do you know how to create a `JPanel` form?

Comment: @Suresh look at your previous post. It shows how to load am image. You're making the same mistake your were before.

Comment: @peeskillet i got to know now am trying with it